# Android unexcpected error

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner of Android and i need a bit hints and help. I am using following code

```
   public class WifiHotSpotActivity extends Activity {

    private Button adnew = null; 


  @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
           init();

        adnew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNewBtn);

        adnew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), addNew.class);
               startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });
   }
```

The error i am receiving is

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.kahaf.wifiHotSpot/com.kahaf.wifiHotSpot.addNew}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

if anyone can tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your activity in the manifest file. Here's an example how your manifest should look after the addition of that activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foo.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".FooActivity" 

            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden">"
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".YourActivityNameHere"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
        </activity>

         <activity 
            android:name=".AnotherActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

put this to AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity android:name=".WifiHotSpotActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've not defined the [Activity Element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) in the manifest xml for WifiHotSpotActivity.  Without this you will be unable to launch this activity.

Answer (score 0):

go to manifest the application tag.. add activity "addNew" which you are calling in button click..